# hiding div having dropdown based on radio button selection knockoutjs

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I am working on KnockoutJS  where i want to hide and show divs having dropdowns  based on radio button selection, however i am succesful doing it if div does not contain dropdown,
please find the link to JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3z2n8LLa/

here when you initially select "Requirement exists" i am showing a div, but when you select any radio button among "Area,Monitor,Other" i want to do the same thing but it works only for first dropdown..

please find the code below

```
    <div class="adminFieldsetContainer" id="RequirementsMain">
    <div>
        <label class="fieldSetControl label" for="RequirementsExist">Requirements exist?:<span class="styleColorRed">*</span>
        </label>
        <div class="inline">
            <input type="radio" name="RequirementsExist" value="Yes" data-bind="checked: RequirementsExist" />Yes</div>
        <div class="inline">
            <input type="radio" name="RequirementsExist" value="No" data-bind="checked: RequirementsExist" />No</div>
    </div>
    <div data-bind="visible: (RequirementsExist() == 'Yes')">
        <div>
            <label class="fieldSetControl label" for="Experience">Experience Category:<span class="styleColorRed">*</span>
            </label>
            <div class="inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Experience" value="Area" data-bind="checked: Experience" />Area</div>
            <div class="inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Experience" value="Monitor" data-bind="checked: Experience">Monitor</div>
            <div class="inline">
                <input type="radio" name="Experience" value="Other" data-bind="checked: Experience">Other</div>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: (Experience() == 'Area')">
            <p>
                <select class="fieldsetLabelWIdthBigger" id="optionTherapeuticArea" data-bind="options: therapeuticArea"></select>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: (Experience() == 'Monitor')">
            <p>
                <select class="fieldsetLabelWIdthBigger" id="optionTherapeuticArea" data-bind="options: therapeuticArea"></select>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="visible: (Experience() == 'Other')">
            <p>Other</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

viewmodel code

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.RequirementsExist = ko.observable();
    self.Experience = ko.observable();
    self.JobRole = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

help would be appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `select` elements have a binding to an observable that doesn't exist on your model, which shows up as an error in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "options: function
>   (){return therapeuticArea }" Message: therapeuticArea is not defined

If you remove the bindings from your `select` elements, [it works as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/4uypmwm2/1/)